# How to enable developer settings in android 5.1, instead of LOLLIPOP game

Tags: settings, hidden

I want to  access developer setting in my phone, but it is not showing all settings. It has developer options but there is only one switch button for switching Developer options and USB Debugging settings. I searched on internet and many sites, they said that in LOLLIPOP devices, developer settings are hidden. we can enable them by clicking 5 or 7 on Build-number in About section in the settings. In my phone, when I navigate to Settings>About Phone> there is no option with containing word 'Build'. but when I click 5 or 7 times on Android Version option it open a game of LOLLIPOP instead of developer settings. Can anyone tell me how can I enable developer settings in my android LOLLIPOP phone???
Thank you in  advance....

I have Q-Mobile i6i with android 5.1.

Comment: Post a screenshot of About Phone settings?

Comment: Yeah, a screenshot would be good. Maybe if it's a custom ROM they've removed it or relocated it to somewhere else in the settings (where, I do not know).

Comment: Did you try scrolling to the bottom of Settings->"About Phone"?

Comment: I've uploaded screenshots on Google Drive, these screenshots are public: here is link:

[Screenshot #1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3CLznSDmoEJYzMzaGR4SkUzczA/view?usp=sharing/).
[Screenshot #2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3CLznSDmoEJRXpxLW1MZUFheEk/view?usp=sharing/).
[Screenshot #3](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3CLznSDmoEJblpDdFVRZ0U4NWM/view?usp=sharing/).

BUILD-NUMBER option is not inculuded in my phone's settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In vanilla AOSP builds, the *Build number* menu is the last one on the *About phone* panel. From your screenshot, your device instead has *Software version* in that location. Try the 5-7 clicks on this area. If that doesn't do anything, or produces a message like *"No need, you are already a developer."*, then I'm afraid your OEM has removed this ability and given you only minimal *Developer options* capability in the form of a *USB debugging* switch. The good part is that it's already enabled so at least you have that.

Also, the Lollipop game that you found after multiple clicks on *Android version* is also what happens in normal AOSP devices.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think you are right. Manufacturer have removed or excluded or disabled _developer settings_  from settings menu . Can you tell me how can I enable these settings if these are disabled by default, or include or even install if these are excluded or not part of the OS in this phone???

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the vendor of your phone removed these options by way of source code modifications when they built the custom ROM for your device.  This means that you would have to go back to the source code, add back the missing/disabled code, rebuild the ROM and finally flash it to the device. Since that isn't possible, you're best bet might be trying an alternative like CyanogenMod, if it's available for your device model.

Comment: Are there specific developer options that you need?  If you are using the phone to test apps, all you really need is the USB debugging setting so you can sideload from Android Studio or issue commands via `adb`.  So unless you need some obscure developer setting, you might be able to do what you need with what you have now.

Comment: Yeah, you guessed it right.  I am using my phone for debugging and testing apps, I was looking for options like _show layout bounds, allow mock locations , etc_. But I think either I need to change device or use emulator/virtual device to test apps. Thank you for your cooperation....

Comment: Thank you again, I've accepted your answer because it cleared all the confusions about unavailability of options. I've up voted your all comments and answer, as soon as my reputations become 15 or more, your votes will increment automatically.... Bundle of Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Click on build number in about, sveral times, you willl enable developer mode and then you can enable usb debuging.

Comment: Dear @BinaryArcam I've already mentioned that this procedure did not make any change. I have uploaded url links screenshots of settings list in my previous comments. Please review these screenshots and tell me if you need more details.